# Can't install Acquia Drupal Commons locally

Tags: drupal, mamp, drupal-commons, acquia

Working on a MacbookPro OS 10.6.6 , using MAMP Pro 1.9.4.

I'm attempting to install Acquia's Drupal Commons locally. The installation progress bar goes all the way, I can check in phpMyadmin that the database has been populated, but before the site configuration screen , I get a 500 Server Error!

Standard Drupal 6 or 7 install without any problem & I was able to install Drupal Commons on my web server. So it seems that some form of conflicts happens between my server configuration ( Mamp Pro ) and Drupal Commons.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by raising the PHP limit in Mamp to 96M.

```
  File > Edit Template > PHP > PHP Version
  //Search for 'memory_limit' & edit the value 
  memory_limit = '96M';
```

then restart the server.

After dong this Drupal Commons should install without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that your sites/default/default.settings.php file was copied to settings.php and not just renamed?

I remember having problems setting up Drupal when I just renamed it, both files need to be there.

Comment: thanks but as i mentioned earlier, i have no problems with a standard Drupal installation & i'm also able to install Commons on my web server!